# Do we have to use present continuous verb before "continues"?

Tags: british-english, spoken-english

Just like

> the killing continues
>
> the dancing continues

Or is it ok to use some other tense before "continues"

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the present continuous; those are noun phrases based on the gerund (identical in form to the present participle).

Any noun which refers to an action could be used before continues

> The dance continues
>
> The song continues
>
> The singing continues

Some of these are less likely to be used.

Comment: I found a written instance of [*And the kill continues*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4yO-Fn7LSJMC&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=%22the+kill+continues%22&source=bl&ots=K4vkzPXnFb&sig=VUVVX528El5ehG3NvyZrGHdlGME&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQvbH_mOfZAhUJBcAKHS5KCYoQ6AEIRjAG#v=onepage&q=%22the%20kill%20continues%22&f=false), which mirrors your ***dance*** example. It's important for learners to note that ***dance*** and ***kill*** are *not* verb forms in such contexts - they're nouns in their own right (although I must admit ***kill*** isn't often used like that).